# Re-ask question on different StackExchange site

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

I would like to re-ask [a particular unanswered question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16073/average-height-of-regular-trees) on math.stackexchange. Is it OK to do so? Or should I ask for migration?

The meta discussions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/duplicate-on-other-se-site) seem to recommend "normally no, unless you have some good reasons to do so (and if you cross-link the questions)".

I believe I have good reasons, as the topic touches both computer science (in this case regular grammars) and math (asymptotic analysis) and is unanswered, yet I would still rather get a recommendation before I get on peoples' nerves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think three days is not a long time for a question that

1. has to be seen by an expert and
2. is likely to require some research and/or thought,

especially since these days have been weekdays all.

We can migrate up to 60 days. I recommend you wait for a week or two. If no (satisfying) answer has come up until then, we can migrate or you repost and add an answer here later.

I'd prefer the latter option because I think the question is a good addition to this site.

Update: The question went unanswered for a while. Since it's too late to migrate now, it's been [reposted to cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20649/is-there-a-regular-tree-language-in-which-the-average-height-of-a-tree-of-size#).

Comment: I have added a bounty in order to draw attention to the nice question.

Comment: OK. Thanks for adding the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

That question is firmly on-topic here. Nonetheless, since it's gone unanswered and you're willing, we might migrate it away if you think it has a better chance of getting a reply elsewhere. Wouldn't [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) be a better fit though? I can migrate to either Math or TCS, but I'd like a third opinion from someone more familiar than us with these sites before doing so.

Comment: A migration to Theoretical Computer Science might also be appropriate, yes. I understand that you prefer migration over re-posting, that's fine with me.